# ROS Gazebo error on open URDF (roslaunch error)

Tags: ros, gazebo, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, I'm working with an hexapod in a project, so i need to import it from solid works to gazebo. I tried to use an URDF exporter, and it generated an folder with 2 launchs (gazebo.launch & display.launch). I tried to execute the gazebo.launch with roslaunch. It bring me an error https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5e56cbfb2f6b3f24de0d

So I openned my .launch file: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/244301079d768c7aaf75

And change some lines, getting this: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/57f95f42fb4b5cfc4ebc

And now it is returning the following error: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6f603553edcc25128ae5

Someone know waht should i do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199627/ros-gazebo-error-on-open-urdf-(roslaunch-error)/) by [Marcio Montenegro](https://answers.ros.org/users/21139/marcio-montenegro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-12-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-12-16**:
Do you have gazebo installed? And the ROS components? The error message that you linked to suggests you don't (or at least: ROS can't find the `gazebo_worlds` package).

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2014-12-17**:
For future reference, it is probably better if you post code and the relevant errors directly on this page so people that are searching for answers to similar problems will find them here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you are using ROS Hydro, there is no package called "gazebo" in Hydro, it has been replaced with [gazebo_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/gazebo_ros?distro=hydro). Additionally, this [page](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_roslaunch&cat=connect_ros#Tutorial:UsingroslaunchtostartGazebo,worldfilesandURDFmodels) has really good information about how to launch a URDF in gazebo from ROS. Here is their example:

`<!-- Spawn a robot into Gazebo --> <node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-file $(find baxter_description)/urdf/baxter.urdf -urdf -z 1 -model baxter" />`

It looks like what you are doing should work, you're just using the wrong "pkg". Also I notice you have `../robots/hexapod_launch.URDF-urdf"` 
There should be a space between .URDF and -urdf.

Long story short, try this

```
<node 
name="spawn_model" 
pkg="gazebo_ros" 
type="spawn_model" 
args="-file ../robots/hexapod_launch.URDF -urdf -model hexapod_launch" 
output="screen" />
```

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2014-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcio Montenegro](https://answers.ros.org/users/21139/marcio-montenegro/) on 2015-02-03**:
I'm getting this error https://gist.github.com/anonymous/751b0435785d5e331b32